# Saving and retrieving custom object from NSUserdefaults is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I am trying to save a custom object to NSUserDefaults but it doesn't work.  Here is the code.

/// User.m ////////////

```
#import "User.h"


@implementation User

....


+ (User *)getUser {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *myEncodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:kUser];
User *obj = (User *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject];
return obj;

}


- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
//Encode properties, other class variables, etc

 [encoder encodeObject:self.address1 forKey:@"address1"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.address2 forKey:@"address2"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.city forKey:@"city"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.country forKey:@"country"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.created_at forKey:@"created_at"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.emergency_contact_name forKey:@"emergency_contact_name"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.emergency_contact_phone_number   forKey:@"emergency_contact_phone_number"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.facetime_email forKey:@"facetime_email"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.gender forKey:@"gender"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.password forKey:@"password"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.phone_number forKey:@"phone_number"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.photo_url forKey:@"photo_url"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.role forKey:@"role"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.security_answer forKey:@"security_answer"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.security_question forKey:@"security_question"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.state forKey:@"state"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.updated_at forKey:@"updated_at"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.userID forKey:@"userID"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.username forKey:@"username"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.zip forKey:@"zip"];
 [encoder encodeObject:self.email forKey:@"email"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

if((self = [super init])) {
    //decode properties, other class vars

    self.address1 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"address1"];
    self.address2 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"address2"];
    self.city = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"city"];
    self.country = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"country"];
    self.created_at = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"created_at"];
    self.emergency_contact_name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"emergency_contact_name"];
    self.emergency_contact_phone_number = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"emergency_contact_phone_number"];
    self.facetime_email = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"facetime_email"];
    self.gender = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"gender"];
    self.password = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"password"];
    self.phone_number = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"phone_number"];
    self.photo_url = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"photo_url"];
    self.role = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"role"];
    self.security_answer = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"security_answer"];
    self.security_question = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"security_question"];
    self.state = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"state"];
    self.updated_at = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"updated_at"];
    self.userID = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userID"];
    self.username = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"username"];
    self.zip = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"zip"];
    self.email = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"email"];
}
return self;
}


+ (void)saveUser:(User *)obj {
NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:kUser];
[defaults synchronize];
}

+ (User *)loadUserWithKey:(NSString *)key {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *myEncodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:key];
User *obj = (User *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject];
return obj;
}

+(void)deleteUser {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:nil forKey:kUser];

}


@end
```

/// Here is how I save the user

```
  User *currentUser = [User getUser];
  currentUser.firstname = self.firstNameField.text;
  currentUser.lastname = self.lastNameField.text;
  currentUser.email = self.emailField.text;
  currentUser.password = self.passwordField.text;
  currentUser.phone_number = self.mobileField.text;

  [User saveUser:currentUser];
```

/// Here is how I get it, but it returns with none of the properties set that I set above in during save?  WTF?

```
// Fill the textfields and image with the data
  User *currentUser = [User loadUserWithKey:kUser];
  self.firstNameField.text = currentUser.firstname;
  self.lastNameField.text = currentUser.lastname;
  self.mobileField.text = currentUser.phone_number;
  self.emailField.text = currentUser.email;
```

All currentUser. things are nil;

Comment: Have you run through the debugger? Make sure the call to `saveUser` works and nothing is `nil`. If that is OK then debug the call to `loadUserWithKey:` and check each step for any `nil` objects. Also make sure you don't have a "chicken and egg" problem. You start by calling `getUser` but this assumes you have already saved a user first.

Comment: Its pulling back the archived object but the saved objects properties are nil. When I break point it when saving the object the properties are there. For instance, .firstname shows "Ty" in the User saveUser method.  But coming out of the loadUserWithKey or getUser the firstname field is nil. What is funny is the only field to make it out is phone_number?

Comment: I am missing firstname and lastname from the encoder. I put those in and now they all save fine. Weird that the rest didn't get saved because I was missing two?